# Runing a jar file (standalone java console application) simultaneously with a Web Application

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ibm-cloud

I have been stuck on this problem for a few days. I have googled endlessly and yet still haven't found a solution after a few days. My deadline is pretty much here for my project so you guys are my last resort.

**My Project:**

I have a simple enough web application where you come and submit a file (lets call this a request) and wait for it to be processed. Once you submit the request, the specifics are inserted in a text file and saved. One can check his/her status of the request at any time. This is my client side piece.

I then have a constant 24/7 engine running in the background that keeps checking the aforementioned text file for new requests. Once it finds a new request, it gets to work on it. Once finished it changes its status and changes whatever details it needs to in the text file. In eclipse I run this as a java application. I can also export it as a runnable jar and run it through command line.

**What I want to do:**

I want to be able to combine both of these pieces to work simultaneously together. This means that once I deploy the web app (WAR file), I want the engine to run as well. I am hoping to deploy this on BLUEMIX. I have deployed the client side piece perfectly on BLUEMIX but I just dont know how I can package the engine with it. I am using WebSphere Application Server and Tomcat on Eclipse for testing. It is all working find but I just need to combine both of these pieces into 1. I have tried adding a listener class to the project but the problem is that once I run the engine class it doesn't load my web application since the engine is suppose to just keep running (it has a while loop) until it is terminated.

I am relatively newbie to web application development and if someone can point me in the correct direction that did be very helpful!

Comment: Have you considered using a database or message queue instead of integrating your processes through a text file?  Then you could push the solution as two applications instead of one and integrate them through the service.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I can help you to get what you have running in Bluemix (e.g., by customizing the start up command, or fork another process from Liberty, etc.), I do think that's not the right design for your problem. As already pointed out by others, you can consider to deploy the two parts (the web part and the worker part) as two applications and integrate them through a queue service (like the MQ Light service), or rewrite the worker using a thread pool of Liberty. If the app is meant to process large volume of requests, the first option is better. You can find a sample here on how to do that in Bluemix: https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2015/05/22/getting-started-with-java-apps-using-the-mq-light-service-for-bluemix/

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you want to allow concurrency in your application.

What you are suggesting is having multiple **processes** to achieve this: One to listen to web requests and one to look for changes in a file. Your operating system will support this. I don't know whether your IDE lets you do this (it should, if not try Intellij IDEA), but you can run a command to start each process from the command line once you have deployed your project correctly. At that stage you don't need the IDE any more.

Another option is to introduce **multithreading** into your Java. Threads allow parallelisation within a single Java program. This would mean in your case that the webapp could carry on serving clients while your while loop executes ad infinitum.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html for a tutorial on this.

Answer (score 0):

Change your application client to the MDB (message driven bean), it should be supported by Bluemix Liberty with for example internal JMS engine. Then after you client receives and stores the file, it sends asynchronous JMS message to the MDB with some details. MDB picks up automatically message and processes the file.

If your file is not very big put it in the database, as others suggested, it will be much easier to work with in clustered solutions, if your application gets bigger, and much easier to check/update statuses of the process.